# How do i run ASP.NET MVC 4 with a custom Membership Provider for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have run some mvc 3 applications with custom memberships but for ASP.NET MVC 4 i can not find any example how i do a custom membership provider with MySQL.

Not any example for custom membership i can find, do anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it exactly the same way as MVC 3, however you have to disable the use of SimpleMembership by removing the [InitializeSimpleMembership] attribute on the RegisterModel class.

You also have to remove all the boiler plate that uses SimpleMembership from the AccountController if you generated a sample applciation.

Comment: Thanks going to test it, i only thinked they changed to mutch but i testing.